# Exception when installing packages in IronPython 2.7.7 using Pip

Tags: c#, python, nltk, ironpython

I am trying to install several packages to use it in a C# app via IronPython. However I get the following error when I run `ipy -X:Frames -m pip install package_name` from the windows console:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 299, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 356, in prepare_files
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._prepare_file(
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\utils\logging.py", line 36, in indent_log
    yield
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

**Update:** Before the exception I see two warnings. Maybe they have to do with the problem.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:1: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  from __future__ import absolute_import
C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py:1: SubjectAltNameWarning: Certificate for pypi.python.org has no `subjectAltName`, falling back to check for a `commonName` for now. This feature is being removed by major browsers and deprecated by RFC 2818. (See https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/497 for details.)
  from __future__ import absolute_import
```

I can install NLTK via pip in my separate python installation. I tried to reference these packages via `sys.path.append()` but it doesn't work either. However, I don't think it would be a good solution anyway.

Comment: Have you tried pythonnet?

Comment: Not yet, would be the last resort. Actually, I'd like to use IronPython.

Comment: I'm interested to know what is your use case for IronPython, is it deep integration with C# and CLR?

Comment: I am currently evaluating different ways to call a python API from C#. So in the end I will not have to use IronPython. I might also use pythonnet or even build a REST API in python, for instance with flask, and call that from C#. Just for the purpose of evaluation, I tried to make it work in IronPython. Maybe there are other ways, I haven't thought of.